STM32F103C6T8 max PWM frequency and phase delays
I want to use the STM32F103C6T8 with a base clock of 72 MHz and a timer using an external clock source with a varying frequency of 6-10 MHz. The output should be a PWM with a 25% duty cycle and a frequency that is 1/8th of the external clock source.
I'm concerned about the latency of the timer module — how many operations does it add, and what is the maximum PWM frequency it can handle? (for example arduino nano can generate only about 62KHZ signal from a 16Mhz refernce)
Also, how can I ensure that the output signal is in phase with the external clock source?

External frequency have to be lower then half of timer frequency (72MHz). AFAIK timers (and its outputs) in STM32F103 are synchronous to internal clock (72MHz resp. 36MHz). Thus there will be jitter up to 1/72us in timer output relative to input of external clock - strictly speaking timer output is not in phase with input clock in that case (with exception when external clock is synchronous to MCU clock).
Let me correct you. Arduino Nano with 16MHz clock, can generate PWM with frequency up to 4MHz if you need only 25% DCL. There is relationship between MCU(timer) clock, PWM frequency and PWM resolution. You can get higher frequencies if you lower PWM resolution. The same rules aply also to most STM32 timers.
